# how do I setup Apache's Content-Encoding Header?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, http-headers, mod-deflate

When attempting to validate my site with the W3C validator, it returns the error, "Don't know how to decode Content-Encoding 'none'". Firebug confirms that my server is sending the header, "Content-Encoding: none".

But I can't find any directive in apache2.conf or in my vhost that sets the Content-Encoding header.

Where does the directive go, and what should it be set to?

UPDATE:

On further examination it seems something is wrong with mod_deflate (gzip). It's zipping my css files just fine, but is not zipping the html generated by my php scripts.

I have:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css
```

And the pages are showing a mime type of: "text/html". But content encoding is "none" and they aren't zipping. Perhaps these issues are related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header was being set by the PHP script, not in Apache. I didn't even think to look there until I stumbled on it by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks right. What is the encoding for static .html files? If those are fine, look at how you are generating HTML from PHP ... perhaps ... ?

Comment: My robots.txt file is gziped, and error messages (404, etc) are too. But my php files on this particular vhost are showing "content-encoding: none". On another vhost, php files are zipped correctly. The only difference I can see is that the files are delivered via mod_rewrite on the problem vhost, and "straight" on the one that works. Wonder if that's a known issue?

Comment: Could be ... any chance you have a vhost were you can reproduce this? I glanced at the apache docs for mod_rewrite (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) but didn't see anything there. Or ... try moving the "AddOutputFilterByType" line before (or after) the rewrites ... ?